# Django admin ImproperlyConfigured issue

Tags: django, django-admin

I've got a strange issue with my Django site, running on the local dev web server for testing.  I'm developing on different machines, and on one computer, the site works fine.  On the other, I keep getting an Improperly Configured error, saying that EmployeeAdmin is not a callable or an attribute of 'EmployeeAdmin' or found in the model 'Employee'.  The thing is, I don't have an EmployeeAdmin class anywhere in the site, though I used to.  Is there some sort of caching going on with the Admin stuff that I need to clear out?  I looked at the django_ tables in the database and don't see anything there.  I'd put code here, but since I've done a complete site text search and made sure that EmployeeAdmin class doesn't exist, I don't know what to upload here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe some old .pyc files laying around? Maybe your PYTHONPATH is pointing somewhere it shouldn't? Maybe you are using the wrong settings file? Just some random ideas to check...

Comment: If you want to answer the question I'll accept it.  It was the admin.pyc file that for whatever reason hadn't been removed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have an old .pyc file laying around that is tripping you up?